# Win10 How to whitelist Apps for Admin Privileges?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

i have a few applications that need admin privileges everytime i run them, and i always give them. Can i somehow whitelist certain applications to run as admin without me clicking "Yes"? I do not want to turn off User Account Control Completely, i just dont want to get asked about certain apps.

I know about the consequences that could have, like if an app "turns evil" and updates malware, it would have admin privileges - i dont care about that. Is there a way to whitelist single apps to not ask me anymore?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Users get admin privileges not programs. If a program needs extra privileges then it should be a service or scheduled task. But then you won't be able to interact with it..

Comment: At one time, it was possible to use Scheduled Tasks to run an application with elevated privileges: https://winaero.com/blog/create-elevated-shortcut-to-skip-uac-prompt-in-windows-10/ . However, at least on Window 10 v. 1909, that loophole has been effectively closed, because the shortcut to the task *also* must be run as Administrator, requiring UAC prompt. That said, you *could* create a Scheduled Task to start apps on login.

Comment: Windows does not support what you describe.  The closest think would to save your credentials, but that does not really work, when you need to elevate the permissions of a specific process.  Saving your credentials would only be helpful if you are talking about starting a process from within a script.  This also requires you save your password, so anyone can read it, within the source for the script.

Answer (score 0):

No. Certainly not for the vast majority. Administrator is now just that and other users are Standard.

So short of giving people Admin credentials (bad idea) then the regular Support people have to help the users.

You (yourself) need to continue to provide credentials. You can try making a shortcut that runs with elevated credentials and that may help you.

That is the way it has been for a long while.

If you have a lot of this, look to Power Broker

http://www.beyondtrust.com/PowerBroker-Desktops-Windows-Edition.aspx?section=PowerBroker-Desktops-Windows-Edition

Answer (score 0):

I haven't needed to do this recently, but in the past I've used both RunAsSpc and Steelsonic RunAs to accomplish what I think you're trying to do.

https://www.robotronic.de/runasspcen.html

http://www.steelsonic.com/steelrunas.htm